# How to I get all open pull requests opened by my user with github api?

Tags: python, rest, github, github-api

How to I get all open pull requests opened by my user with github api?

Am looking to get these from Python but as long REST calls can do it, I am fine.

Keep in mind that I do want all PRs from all repositories owned by me. After this I will also want to get all open PRs where I was asked to be a reviewer (those that I need to review).

Answer (score -2):

You can use [GitHub API /pulls endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests) to fetch a user's Pull Requests.

But in short, you can use this URL

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls?head=user:{USERNAME-HERE}
```

For private repositories, you need to authenticate yourself first.
https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication

And lastly, to list all pull requests which you are a reviewer, take a look at [this](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/review_requests/). There is no direct way to list all pull requests waiting for review from you but first, you can list all pull requests and later filter them.

GET /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls/:pull_number/requested_reviewers